Identify a game like War where each player chooses their card
In this 2 players game, each player starts with a hand of entire single suit (13 cards from Ace to King). Both players choose a card each round for 13 rounds, and each round the higher card wins. Cards are discarded after you use them. The winner is the player who wins the most rounds by the end.

Where are the cards? In the players' hands? Or face up/down on the table? Aren't there 26 cards, if they choose one card each for 13 rounds? Or is it a full deck with half the cards dealt?

@WeatherVane, each player is holding a hand of 13 cards of a single suit, for example: p1 gets all the hearts while p2 gets all the spades.  The other suits are not used in the OP version.  In the official Goofspiel another suit is used to decide the value of each round.

Isn't this totally boring, because you just play your cards from highest to lowest and are guaranteed to maximize your gain? Am I missing something? I know this is just a description to identify the game, but I am curious.

@Antares, no.  If you play your cards from highest to lowest, and I play in the first turn my lowest, then go from highest to lowest, I will win 12 out of the 13 turns.

Goofspiel
This is a variant of Goofspiel with a single difference: in your version, prizes are equal (each win is worth 1 point), while in the official Goofspiel, each round is worth 1 to 13 points (at the start of each round, you reveal a card from another suit of 13 cards to determine the prize value of the round).
This game falls within the domain of the Colonel Blotto game, which is studied intensively by game theorists.
